# Change form action based on form select field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I can't get the form action to change based on a user's drop-down selection. What I want to do is have the form redirect to a different page, then the default for the form if a user selects "Student Loans" from the select field named "agency".

In other words, what I want to do is that if someone select "student loans" for the agency, I want the page to submit to /quote/quotes-sl.php instead of quote/quotes.php (the default of the form).

Here is my form code:

```
<form id="tdhcustom-pre-1-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="submit_function(this)" action="/quote/quotes.php" method="post" name="tdhcustom-pre-1-form">
<input id="edit-lead-source-description" name="lead_source_description" type="hidden" value="test" />
<label class="edit-owed" for="edit-owed"> Amount Owed: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span>
</label><select id="owed" class="form-select required" name="owed">
<option selected="selected" value="">Select...</option>
<option value="$10,000 to $14,999">$10,000 to $14,999</option>
<option value="$15,000+">$15,000+</option>
</select>
<label class="edit-agency" for="edit-agency"> Problem With: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span>
</label><select id="agency" class="form-select required" name="agency">
<option selected="selected" value="">Select Agency...</option>
<option value="Student Loan" data-action="/quote/quotes-sl.php">Student Loan</option>
<option value="FEDERAL">Federal Taxes</option>
<option value="STATE">State Taxes</option>
</select></div>
<input id="edit-submit" class="form-submit" height="31" name="submit" src="test.com/test.jpg" type="image" value="Submit" width="214" />
<input id="form-5ezy7kqpVIYFiVUgKIyxbp4n6MQ7ZqHuo33GJbq0QZE" name="form_build_id" type="hidden" value="form-5ezy7kqpVIYFiVUgKIyxbp4n6MQ7ZqHuo33GJbq0QZE" />
<input id="edit-tdhcustom-pre-1-form" name="form_id" type="hidden" value="tdhcustom_pre_1_form" />
</form>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
function submit_function(form) {
    var selected = document.getElementById('Agency');
    var dataset = selected[selected.selectedIndex].dataset;

    if (dataset.action) {
        form.action = dataset.action;
    }
    return true;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Change the form `action` when an `onchange` event is triggered on you `<select>` ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to change the form action based on an `onchange` event from your `<select>` ... but you'll also want to remove the `onsubmit` attribute from your form, like so:

```
<form id="tdhcustom-pre-1-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/quote/quotes.php" method="post" name="tdhcustom-pre-1-form">
```

Assuming you're going to have data attributes on all the options like this:

```
<select id="agency" class="form-select required" name="agency">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select Agency...</option>
    <option value="Student Loan" data-action="/quote/quotes-sl.php">Student Loan</option>
    <option value="FEDERAL" data-action="/quote/quotes-s2.php">Federal Taxes</option>
    <option value="STATE" data-action="/quote/quotes-s3.php">State Taxes</option>
</select>
```

You can just replace your `<script>` block with:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var theForm = document.getElementById('tdhcustom-pre-1-form');
    var theSelector = document.getElementById('agency');

    theSelector.onchange = function() {
        theForm.action = theSelector[theSelector.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-action');
    }
})();
</script>
```

That's pure JavaScript - so without jQuery (or any other framework).

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is still not working. Do I need to put onchange=? or something on selection field for agency? Here is code:

<select id="agency" class="form-select required" name="agency">
<option selected="selected" value="">Select Agency...</option>
<option value="Student Loan" data-action="/quote/quotes-sl.php">Student Loan</option>
<option value="STATE" data-action="/quote/quotes.php">State</option>
<option value="FEDERAL_AND_STATE" data-action="/quote/quotes.php">Federal and State</option>
</select>

Comment: not sure if this means anything but the console in chrome says this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Comment: @charliec - sorry, would have responded to the comment sooner but I had to take the dog out :) Glad you worked the last bit out ;)

Comment: If I have a mobile version of the form and a desktop version, can I just put the same script twice and give the mobile version a different form ID and name and it will work? Essentially that is the case I just didn't put in question because it would be too much code on page. But I have a mobile version of the form and and desktop version depending on user and solution doesn't work but if I take off one of the forms (desktop or mobile) it does.

Comment: Make the form responsive and just have the one that works on both desktop and mobile - that's the best thing to do.

Comment: Should I ask another question? The page we have has two forms on it but only shows one based on user viewport. Therefore, both forms have the same ID and name but with the javascript you gave me only one of them works as intended. Any ideas to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Add trigger on selected option val = "Student Loan" , then change **attribute "action"** form to **url "/quote/quotes-sl.php"**

```
    $('#agency').on('change',function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        if(selected == "Student Loan")
            $('#tdhcustom-pre-1-form').prop('action',"/quote/quotes-sl.php");
    });
```

CMIIW :D

Comment: please add some context and/or explanation to your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked as well. Again, the issue was playing javascript under the form which I didn't have.